# How to create generic build and release on VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

While adopting microservices architecture, we identified that we have a lot of projects with the very same structure.

.Net and .Net Core projects more specifically and the most of them are published as Azure App Services (Web Apps).

Today we have to configure a Build definition and a Release definition for each project/app.

Is there a way to have only one Build definition and one Release definition that can be triggered by any checkin, build specific project and create a release that publishes to a specific app service?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it’s possible. You can a build and release definition to build/deploy different type of projects separately.

Assume you have two projects in git repo:

```
root
  |___ .git      
  |___ dotnetProject
             |___ dotnetProject.sln
             |___ dotnetProject
                       |___ dotnetProject.csproj
                       |___ …
  |___ dotnetCoreProject
             |___ dotnetCoreProject.sln
             |___ dotnetCoreProject
                       |___ dotnetCoreProject.csproj
                       |___ …
```

Detail setps as below:

1. Add all tasks you need to build and deploy for your projects in build and release definition.
2. Define two variables `dotnet` and `dotnetCore` with default value `0` in your build and release definition separately.
3. Set custom condition for the tasks that you need to build/deploy for different type of projects.

   - For the tasks to build/deploy for .NET project, use below custom condition:
     [image]
   - For the tasks to build/deploy for .NET Core project, use below custom condition:
     [image]
4. Detect which project(s) is/are changed for CI build by add a PowerShell task.

   Add a PowerShell task at the beginning of the tasks and check which file(s) has been changed by last commit. If .NET project has been changed, set `dotnet` variable with value `1` and create a file `dotnet` with content `1`. If .NET core project has been changed set variable `dotnetCore` with value `1` and create a file `dotnetCore` with content `1`.

   **Note:** you should also publish the files `dotnet` and `dotnetCore` as build artifacts since you should parse the value for `dotnet` and `dotnetCore` variables in release definition based on the files.
5. Change `dotnet` and `dotnetCore` variables value based on the files `dotnet` and `dotnetCore`.

   At the beginning of your release definition, add a PowerShell task. To check if the file `dotnet`/`dotnetCore` in build artifacts. If has, change related variable based on the files content.

Comment: Hi Mariana! Very interesting. But in this case, I want to build any project in the team project with only one build definition and deply any app service using one release definition and this release definition must be able to identify the generated artifacts and publish them to correct app service. Is it possible? May be using variables like in your exemple? Thanksss

Comment: Yes, the example can achieve that. You just need to add multiple Azure App Service Deploy task with different custom conditions. Only the custom condition is meet, the task will be run.